# php-fpm workers eating lots of memory even on zero traffic

Tags: php-fpm

[image: htop dump]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgbDt.pngu

php-fpm workers are taking large amount of memory even if there has been zero traffic on the server for some time. What is this memory? Is it leaked memory (magento is on that pool) or is it some sort of php cache (I use just APC cache which should be in a shared memory somewhere though)?

Here is my config:

```
[www]

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = www
group = www

pm = dynamic    
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5    
pm.max_spare_servers = 35

slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 256M

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

EDIT: I know I am overcommiting my resources a lot here and I have already fixed that but I still wonder what this memory is and why php-fpm does not release it.

Comment: What process manager do you have them running with? Static, ondemand? dynamic?

Comment: It is dynamic. I have added my config file.

Comment: Probably it's because of leaked memory so it cannot be resolved easy way. But you can unload all unnecessary php modules - each of them, even unused, consumes some memory.

Comment: I agree with Krzysztof about the posibility of a memory leak. In addition to his recomendations, try setting the pm.max_requests directive, forcing fpm childs to respawn after processing certain amount of requests.

Comment: Did you try setting process manager to 'ondemand'? And also, you should avoid to load extensions that you don't need. Check you exntensions, uncomment or unload it and then restart it php-fpm. It'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your web server and php-fpm? Not a power cycle, just killing apache/nginx & php-fpm then restarting their daemons.

For Debian based systems it would be:

```
service php5-fpm restart
service apache2 restart
```

Also, your top like resource viewer is weird, I was expecting plain top. Not a big deal. But... that is just me being picky.